# "overnight" we have no cold water at all in bathroom. Hot water works fine. No frozen temps (65+)

Tags: water

I'm a widow and cannot afford to hire a plumber. I will try to fix myself if I knew where to start. Need help to find the cause. All other faucets and water flow in the kitchen and master bathroom are working fine. 
I'd appreciate some guidance/suggestions.

Comment: Toilet working in that bathroom?

Comment: As Kris is pointing out when you say no cold water in the bathroom do you specifically mean Sink, tub/shower and toilet?